# Custom ListView Set background image from SqliteDatabase value in Android Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite, listview

Let's say i created a custom listView to display an "image icon", "title" and "subtitle". and the value of that 3 View will be query from sqlite database.

**This is my main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_result"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="#b5b5b5"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

and this is my **custom.xml,** where i design how the view is organized from my ListView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <!--  ListRow Left side image icon-->
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="3dip"      
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/image_bg" 
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip">

            <ImageView     
                android:id="@+id/word_icon"   
                android:layout_width="50dip"
                android:layout_height="50dip"
                android:contentDescription="@string/descrip"
                android:src="@drawable/word_icon_p"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Title-->
        <TextView
           android:id="@+id/wordTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:text="@string/sample"
            android:textColor="#040404"
            android:typeface="sans" 
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

        <!-- Subtitle -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/wordSub"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/wordTitle"
            android:layout_below="@+id/wordTitle"
            android:text="@string/sample"
            android:textColor="#343434"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

and on my **Sqlite Database**, i have the following table and data

```
--------------------------------------
= KEY_CODE = KEY_NAME = KEY_SUBTITLE = //My Table
-------------------------------------- 
=  p       = Sam_Tit1 = Sam_Sub1     = // This
=  x       = Sam_Tit2 = Sam_Sub2     = // is the
=  n       = Sam_Tit3 = Sam_Sub3     = // Data Value
======================================
```

So, the scenario is, i want to set the text for

```
 -> wordTitle TextView is equal to KEY_NAME,
 -> wordSub TextView is equal to KEY_SUBTITLE, and to set the background image of
 -> word_icon ImageView is equal to KEY_CODE value
```

so the listView will looks like

```
 ====================================
  =            ListView              =
  ====================================
  = word_icon = wordTitle = wordSub  =
  ====================================
  =   p.png   = Sam_Tit1  = Sam_Sub1 =
  =   x.png   = Sam_Tit2  = Sam_Sub2 =
  =   n.png   = Sam_Tit3  = Sam_Sub3 =
  ====================================
```

now, here is my **MainActivity**, i named this as **AndroidListViewCursorAdaptorActivity.Java**

```
public class AndroidListViewCursorAdaptorActivity extends Activity {

        private CountriesDbAdapter dbHelper;
        private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            dbHelper = new CountriesDbAdapter(this);
            dbHelper.open();
            displayListView(); // I call this function to set an Adapter for my ListView
        }

        private void displayListView() {
            Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllCountries();
            // The desired columns to be bound
            String[] columns = new String[] { CountriesDbAdapter.KEY_NAME, CountriesDbAdapter.KEY_SUBTITLE };
            // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
            int[] to = new int[] { R.id.wordTitle, R.id.wordSub };
            // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data
            // as well as the layout information
            dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.custom,
                    cursor, columns, to, 0);
            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            // Assign adapter to ListView
            listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        }
    }
```

So, everything is fine and all is working without error, i set the text of **WordTitle** and **WordSub** and bound it to my **ListView**.
Now, my problem is i'am having some trouble in setting the background image of my **ImageView** which is the **word_icon**. i want to set background image of **word_icon**
depending on **KEY_CODE** value. i'm lock on idea on how do i do that. 
i try to update my **mainActivity** with this code.

```
        private CountriesDbAdapter dbHelper;
        private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;
        private ImageView im;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            dbHelper = new CountriesDbAdapter(this);
            dbHelper.open();
            displayListView(); // I call this function to set an Adapter for my ListView
        }

        private void displayListView() {
            Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllCountries();
            // The desired columns to be bound
            String[] columns = new String[] { 
                CountriesDbAdapter.KEY_CODE, //Trying to fetch the KEY_CODE column
                CountriesDbAdapter.KEY_NAME, 
                CountriesDbAdapter.KEY_SUBTITLE };

            // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
            int[] to = new int[] { 
                R.id.word_icon, //Trying to Put it here
                R.id.wordTitle, 
                R.id.wordSub };
            // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data
            // as well as the layout information
            dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.custom,
                    cursor, columns, to, 0);
            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            // Assign adapter to ListView
            listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        }
```

But no luck, this code doesn't work, as my expected, because i know i need to set the background image like,

```
im.setBackgroundImage(R.Drawable.something_image);
```

but i'm lock on idea and need someone help here. 

so, that's all, i hope there's someone can help me here. just ask for some clarification if ever.
Advance thank's!

Comment: you need to write the custom adapter http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-listview-custom-adapter-with-imageview.html

Comment: Thank's for answer, i got some trouble since i'm just a newbie... since the link show's only how to use a custom adapter for listview with an imageView i can't sync it to my own because there's no sqlite database just like mine..